# From quarterly to annual data

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, time-series, lubridate

I have a dataframe that looks like follows:

```
head(df_HPI)
```

[image]

The HPI is a quarterly index I want to convert to annual. I have 17 regions (i.e. CCAA), so I want to aggregate the HPI to contain annual data per region. I made some changes but the code is not working.

```
# Convert series to annual data
df_HPI <- df_HPI_original

# Replace period format 
df_HPI <- data.frame(sapply(df_HPI, function(x) {gsub("T1","-01-01",x)})) # Q1
df_HPI <- data.frame(sapply(df_HPI, function(x) {gsub("T2","-04-01",x)})) # Q2
df_HPI <- data.frame(sapply(df_HPI, function(x) {gsub("T3","-07-01",x)})) # Q3
df_HPI <- data.frame(sapply(df_HPI, function(x) {gsub("T4","-10-01",x)})) # Q4

# Convert column into a date
df_HPI$Periodo <- as.Date(df_HPI$Periodo)

# Aggregate to annual data
df_HPI %>%
  mutate(Year=year(Periodo),
         Quarter=quarter(Periodo),
         Finyear = ifelse(Quarter <= 2, Year, Year+1)) %>% 
  group_by(Finyear, CCAA) %>%
  summarise(HPIy=mean(HPI))
```

In the last step, the programme says the argument is not logical and returns NAs.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I think you’ll need to provide a sample of the data for others to replicate your problem. Look up making a good reprex for R.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I'll suggest this [guideline](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for asking questions. It will maximize your chances of having good and quick answers.You can put the first few line of your table by doing `dput(head(df_HPI))` so we have some data to work with and make sure our answer is as close as possible to what you expect. I would suggest also to avoid using `magrittr` and  all the fancy stuffs. Build a basic function to understand the problem first.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `HPI` column was converted to a factor when you replaced the period format via `gsub`. You therefore have to convert it back to numeric. Try this:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

set.seed(42)

# Example data
quarters <- paste0("T", c(1:4))
years <- c("2019", "2020")
dates <- c(paste0(years[[1]], quarters), paste0(years[[2]], quarters))

df_HPI <- data.frame(
  Periodo = rep(dates, 2),
  CCAA = c(rep("Region1", 8), rep("Region2", 8)),
  HPI = runif(16)
)
head(df_HPI)
#>   Periodo    CCAA       HPI
#> 1  2019T1 Region1 0.9148060
#> 2  2019T2 Region1 0.9370754
#> 3  2019T3 Region1 0.2861395
#> 4  2019T4 Region1 0.8304476
#> 5  2020T1 Region1 0.6417455
#> 6  2020T2 Region1 0.5190959

# Replace period format 
df_HPI <- data.frame(sapply(df_HPI, function(x) {gsub("T1","-01-01",x)})) # Q1
df_HPI <- data.frame(sapply(df_HPI, function(x) {gsub("T2","-04-01",x)})) # Q2
df_HPI <- data.frame(sapply(df_HPI, function(x) {gsub("T3","-07-01",x)})) # Q3
df_HPI <- data.frame(sapply(df_HPI, function(x) {gsub("T4","-10-01",x)})) # Q4

# Convert column into a date
df_HPI$Periodo <- as.Date(df_HPI$Periodo)

# Problem: HPI was converted to a factor 
class(df_HPI$HPI)
#> [1] "factor"
# Solution: Convert back to numeric
df_HPI$HPI <- as.numeric(as.character(df_HPI$HPI))

# Aggregate to annual data
df_HPI %>%
  mutate(Year=year(Periodo),
         Quarter=quarter(Periodo),
         Finyear = ifelse(Quarter <= 2, Year, Year+1)) %>% 
  group_by(Finyear, CCAA) %>%
  summarise(HPIy=mean(HPI))
#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#> # Groups:   Finyear [3]
#>   Finyear CCAA     HPIy
#>     <dbl> <fct>   <dbl>
#> 1    2019 Region1 0.926
#> 2    2019 Region2 0.681
#> 3    2020 Region1 0.569
#> 4    2020 Region2 0.592
#> 5    2021 Region1 0.436
#> 6    2021 Region2 0.701
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>